# What does og:image meta data do with the Facebook Like iframe?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

I am working on putting the Facebook "Like" iframe on a site, and I am trying to follow the example found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like.

I am putting in code similar to this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

But when I "Like" a page, it doesn't do anything with the image that I am aware of. Does anyone know what that data is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

type the url of a page that has the og:image property into your share box and it will auto retrieve the og data to post the link in your feed. this includes the image, description etc. It is also used when you pull the related data using the open-graph api.

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with the "Like" button?

Comment: It lets you define the image that is associated with your page when someone presses the like button.

Comment: At least, it is supposed to. I haven't gotten it to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same.  I've added the two xmlns to the html tag and I've also tried implementing via the xfbml version of the plugin and I still cannot get the meta data to appear in the Facebook feed.  My only thought is that based on FB's description on this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph#extra-data in the "Administering your page" section, that this meta data won't show up in the "Graph" data until 10 people "like" an article, then maybe it comes into play. Otherwise, it seems I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. However, I just made sure that I had all the same tags filled out as in the first example on this page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

Then when I clicked the like button, it appeared with image I'd specified. Also, I ran their scraper thing, not sure if that helped:

curl developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url={YOUR_URL}&format=json

note there should be a http at the front of that curl request. stackoverflow wouldn't let me post more than one link

Comment: also, I made sure I had the same html xmlns attributes as in their example.

Comment: I'll have to try it again, because when I posted this question, doing what you have here didn't do anything with the image at all.

Comment: I think it might take time to update too. was pretty frustrating to get working.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

If you punch the URL where this is posted...it magically tells facebook to stop and post the picture.  I don't know how but it works about 80% of the time.  If og image doesn't work, post an image with `style="display:none;"`. That works for me if og:image does not.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished testing to solve this issue, I spent more than 8 hours on it! :)

If your page has less than 10, like the XFBML, it will not work, you need to use the iframe method.

I don't know why, there is no documentation!

Anyway, I hope that I helped you guys.